# DLR: IAttributesCollection deprecated?

Tags: c#, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

In my code I've been making functions like:

```
public void Foo([ParamsDictionary] IAttributesCollection kwargs) {}
```

But I got curious.  What all implements that interface?  So I pulled down the IronPython source.  In it I found this file:

```
Src\Runtime\Microsoft.Scripting\Runtime\ParamDictionaryAttribute.cs
```

On lines 24-30 it has this:

```
/// Most languages which support params dictionaries will support the following types:
///     IDictionary&lt;string, anything&gt;
///     IDictionary&lt;object, anything&gt;
///     Dictionary&lt;string, anything&gt;
///     Dictionary&lt;object, anything&gt;
///     IDictionary
///     IAttributesCollection (deprecated)
```

Note the deprecated line.  Should I not be using the method signature I had above and instead be using IDictionary<string,object>?  What is the preferred way of declaring my methods?

(Is it possible to bold text in the code sections?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch to using IDictionary or IDictionary.  In IronPython 2.7 IAttributesCollection is actually completely gone.

The reason for this is that IAttributesCollection is basically just a dictionary but with the SymbolId stuff added in.  The SymbolId stuff was originally alright for perf (~10% win in various scenarios when it was added) but it's been made mostly obsolete by the call site infrastructure the DLR now has.  It also has the problem that if you are dynamically generating SymbolId's it causes a memory leak.

The other advantage it had was that it was a simpler API than IDictionary - but that's not much of a reason to to introduce a new type when there's tons of useful implementations of IDictionary.